# pandas groupby-apply missing columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame and i want to do a "groupby-apply" style operation, however, the "key" columns were missing after the operation:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1':['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
'col2':['B1', 'B1', 'B2'],
'col3':[1, 2, 3,]
})  
b1 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], as_index=False)[['col3']].apply(lambda x: x+10)
b2 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], as_index=False)['col3'].apply(lambda x: x+10)
print(b1)
print(b2)
```

b1 will print as:

```
col3
0   11
1   12
2   13
```

b2 will print as:

```
b
0  0    11
1  1    12
2  2    13
Name: col3, dtype: int64
```

how can i make use the group-key columns(['col1','col2'] also be printed, as

```
col1  col2
A1    B1      11
A2    B1      12
A3    B2      13
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a group by here?

Comment: May be just `df['col3'].add(10)`? Why groupby?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have the group keys output. Your calculation returns a `Series` of the original shape of the DataFrame, so the output is a `Series` indexed like the original DataFrame. Your output would be indexed with the group keys when there is an aggregation that gives you one value per group. I.e. the difference between `groupby.sum()` and `groupby.cumsum()`

Comment: It is common output for apply , adding additional index

Comment: ......deleting `as_index=False` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you print the type of each `groupby` `object` you will see , that is `Series`, which will have the index ahead of it . Github Open [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22546)

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], as_index=False)['col3'].apply(lambda x: type(x) )
Out[11]: 
col1  col2
A1    B1      <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
A2    B1      <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
A3    B2      <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
dtype: object
```

To get the expected output

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).apply(lambda x: x['col3']+10).reset_index(level=-1,drop=True)
Out[32]: 
col1  col2
A1    B1      11
A2    B1      12
A3    B2      13
Name: col3, dtype: int64
```